# Is it impossible to implement a federated networking game in the browser without a server?

Tags: networking, browser, client, server

A friend of mine made the statement:

> To share state across browsers - you need a server. You can't federate state across clients.

I get that fundamentally http is a request-response, client-server protocol, and that the browser sandbox has a security design heavily weighted around it being client-only.

I don't know the API well enough, but I found it an interesting question. I wanted to know if there was wiggle-room in this claim.

My question is: **Is it impossible to implement a federated networking game in the browser without a server?** (ie browsers acting as both a server and a client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is possible with WebRTC. The library [PeerJS](http://www.webrtc.org/) uses this.